# Application is dispatching an input-synchronous call - SSIS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ssis

I am getting the following error whenever I open my package:

```
===================================

An outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching an input-synchronous call. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010D (RPC_E_CANTCALLOUT_ININPUTSYNCCALL)) (Microsoft Visual Studio)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSComponentMetaData100.get_Name()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Designer.View.Automation.GraphElementControlAutomationPeer.GetNameCore()
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.GetName()
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.ItemAutomationPeer.GetNameCore()
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireAutomationEvents()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.Process_WM_SIZE(UIElement rootUIElement, IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.LayoutFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Integrated).

Can please somebody explain me this error message?

Comment: If you create a new, empty SSIS project and then close and reopen Visual Studio, do you get the same message? I've not seen this error message before but the general error has to do with the the package validating the metadata in a given dataflow. So the question becomes what sources, destination and lookups are being performed in this package and what's unusual about them?

Comment: No, this is the error message I am getting in a specific solution. I do not get any error when I create a new package. Does this has got something to do with the destination and the associated connection managers?

Comment: Validation is the process where SSIS interrogates the various data providers to ensure that the contract is still valid - does database Y exists, does it contain table X, is column 1 varchar(30), etc. My inclination is that a resource indicated in this package is something unusual (not a database, file, etc) and likely the source of the error message. Until you can provide more details, it makes it rather hard to diagnose. Is there another person at your place of employment that can reproduce your error?

Comment: @billinkc - The project giving the error is not a shared one. I am the only one facing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with validation of a database being referred in the connection manager. Once I updated the connection manager with the correct database, the error got resolved.

Thanks @bilinkc for helping me diagnose the error.